# wrong result when set tdrlevel cuda in win7 64bit

Tags: cuda

when i calculate on cuda , it's true but when i use bigger number for calculating , i have to set TdrLevel as
[this link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/gg487368.aspx)
. but after set tdrlevel , i get a wrong result as this .
(-431602080-431602080-431602080-431602080-431602080-431602080-431602080-431602080-431602080-431602080-431602080-431602080-431602080-431602080-431602080-431602080-431602080-431602080-431602080-431602080-431602080-431602080-431602080-431602080-431602080-431602080-431602080-431602080-431602080-431602080-431602080-431602080-431602080-431602080-431602080-431602080-431602080-431602080-431602080)

i don't know where is problem . count of my block is 512 and count of thread for every block is 1024 . i hope find my mean .

---

```
that's my program code for fibunatchi program it work without tdrlevel but have above result by tdrlevel :


#include <stdio.h>
#include <cuda.h>
#include   <dos.h>


__global__ void fibunat_array(float *a,int N )
{    
    for (int x=0; x< N; x += 1)
    {
        a[x]=0;
    }
    a[0]=1;a[1]=1;  
    for (int i=0; i< N; i += 1)
    {
        a[i+2]=a[i]+a[i+1];       
    }       
}

int main( void )
{
    time_t start,end;
    double dif;
    time ( &start );

    float *a_h,*a_d;
    const int N = 100;

    size_t size = N * sizeof( float );
    a_h = (float *)malloc( size );    

    cudaMalloc( (void **)&a_d, size );  
    cudaMemcpy( a_d, a_h, size, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice );

    int block_size = 9<<1;
    int n_blocks   = (N+ block_size-1) /block_size;
    square_array <<< n_blocks , block_size >>> ( a_d, N );
    cudaMemcpy( a_h, a_d, sizeof( float ) * N, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost );

    for (int i = 0; i<N/3+10 ; i++)
        printf( "%d  ",(int)a_h[i] ); 

    free( a_h );
    cudaFree( a_d );


    time ( &end );
    dif=difftime(end,start);

    printf ( "\n\n");
    printf ( "total time for this calculate is : %d second\n\n",(int)dif);

}
```

Comment: perhaps the tdr disable is not working.  If your display freezes and then repaints itself while you are running the cuda code, the tdr is probably firing and the GPU is getting reset.  If the tdr appears to be correctly disabled, you may have a bug in your code which only shows itself with the larger data set.

Comment: thanks for your answer . i should explain that i add TdrLevel by value of zero in this path:HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\GraphicsDrivers . if don't make this file , screen freeze and black for a moment . but after a lot of search i found that i should add TdrLevel on above path . after adding TdrLevel , screen don't freeze and black but had a wrong result that i explain in first comment . my code is a simple code in sum array. i hope you have a solution for this problem . thanks

Comment: then perhaps your simple array sum program has a bug, that only shows itself for larger values.  It may have nothing to do with the tdr.  You might post your code.  Here's an [example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12659988/cuda-memory-limit-vector-summation) of someone who just posted on an array sum program that didn't work for larger data sets.

Answer (score 1):

This code has several problems.  For example one problem is that you define the kernel with a name of fibunat_array but you invoke a kernel with a name of square_array.  So the code as you posted would not even compile correctly.   Another problem is that your kernel is written from the standpoint of what serial code would do to solve the problem, with no consideration given for running threads in parallel.  Each of the threads created when you launch the kernel will run exactly the same code.  That will not work if multiple threads/blocks are used, and is not a good way to take advantage of the machine.

You appear to be wanting to compute the first 100 numbers in the fibonacci sequence.  You may want to consider the implications of this.   This [page](http://www.maths.surrey.ac.uk/hosted-sites/R.Knott/Fibonacci/fibFormula.html) may help. For example, some of the largest numbers in this sequence range will not fit in a 64 bit integer.  With 32 bit code your unsigned integer size will be too small after about 47 numbers in the sequence.  Also, creating a parallel fibonacci generator will probably require an algorithm that doesn't resemble the serial algorithm you have in mind.

Even if you did create a parallel fibonacci generator, and let's assume each thread computed 1 element of the series, you'd run out of (64-bit) machine resolution within 100 elements, meaning the most parallelism you could get out of the machine would be less than 100 threads worth (under these assumptions).  That's a lot of work to produce something that probably won't give very satisfying results in terms of speedup over the serial algorithm.  Generally speaking, the GPU gives best results when we can have many thousands of threads to run.

Having said all that, you can get something to work if just for a proof point.  Since there are a few problems in your original work, it's simpler for me to just present some code that does produce correct results.  This isn't what I'd call sensible use of the GPU, but you can get correct results this way with some small changes to your original code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cuda.h>
// #include   <dos.h>


__global__ void fib(float *a,int N )
{
    for (int x=0; x< N; x += 1)
    {
        a[x]=0;
    }
    a[0]=1;a[1]=1;
    for (int i=0; i< (N-2); i += 1)
    {
        a[i+2]=a[i]+a[i+1];
    }
}

int main( void )
{
//    time_t start,end;
//    double dif;
//    time ( &start );

    float *a_h,*a_d;
    const int N = 40;

    size_t size = N * sizeof( float );
    a_h = (float *)malloc( size );

    cudaMalloc( (void **)&a_d, size );
    cudaMemcpy( a_d, a_h, size, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice );

   //  int block_size = 9<<1;
   //  int n_blocks   = (N+ block_size-1) /block_size;
   fib<<<1,1>>> ( a_d, N ); // just one thread does all the work
   cudaMemcpy( a_h, a_d, sizeof( float ) * N, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost );

   for (int i = 0; i<N ; i++)
     printf( "%d  ",(int)a_h[i] );

   printf("\n");
   free( a_h );
   cudaFree( a_d );


//    time ( &end );
//    dif=difftime(end,start);

//    printf ( "\n\n");
//    printf ( "total time for this calculate is : %d second\n\n",(int)dif);

}
```

I've commented out the timing portions.  You can uncomment that if you like.  The timing won't be impressive since we're not using any of the parallelism in the GPU.  In addition there are various peculiarities of this code, one of the most obvious being that we're only launching one thread, and in effect using the GPU as a serial machine.  Since this is not the way to do GPU programming, you should not use this as an instructive example.  There are many examples of good GPU programming to be had in the [CUDA SDK](http://developer.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-cc-sdk-code-samples), as well as various other resources on the web.

Comment: thanks robert . about first problem i change name of methode here in site and forget change name of methode in main . at all thanks a lot for your full explain . it could help me for get better result.